# Installing driver for Asus USB-AC56 - part 2

Tags: drivers

This was predominantly answered in this thread
[How do I install an ASUS USB-AC56 WiFi adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404881/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-ac56-wifi-adapter)

Unlike the original requester the instruction provided by chili555 (sorta) works* for me, even on USB2.0 port 
The device shows as Realtek 802.11n NIC

Installed the driver I indicated in the original post from the rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master package (this is a revision 4.2.2 driver):
The Good news - again that install completes and sees the USB adapter and allows it to connect to my router;
The Bad news - compared to the internal adapter the measured download speed (using a browser speedtest) is only about 7Mbps vs 40Mbps (7 at best and EXTREMELY sensitive to position)

Now - I found however, that if I am in direct line of sight of the router, the speed comes up to normal - so somehow it appears there is potentially less power to the device, which is affecting its range?
The same device in the same physical location running under windows is flawless.

1) AC56 vs internal adapter performs much slower when both at same physical location removed from direct line of sight of router

2) In the same physical location, the AC56 performs much worse under Linux than Windows

=> Perhaps less power to the device in Linux which is affecting its range?

- However the download speed is really slow:
  I only get about 1.3 Mbps on this adapter; 20Mbs on the internal adapter; I get over 50 Mbps in Windows. 
  i.e. I know its not my ISP or my adapter itself - something is choking it in Ubuntu

**Problem Statements:**

1. The 4.2.2 driver referenced above will successfully 'make' and install and fundamentally work; however unless within immediate close-proximity, line-of-sight to router, the performance will be severely compromised.
2. The 4.2.5 driver from the Asus site, which appears from the overview may address this performance issue, will not install.

So I have a related question which may or not resolve the speed issue - how to install the Proprietary Asus driver module

The original syntax per link above showed to download that specific driver file and how to load it:

however I have since found the Asus proprietary driver for Linux off the Asus web-site: https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBAC56/#support

It seems like the latest driver listed on the Asus site might address the issue I'm seeing with the limited range with the open-source driver

> **Update MAC/BB/RF parameters and mechanism to improve overall performance.**

But I simply CANNOT get this driver loaded.

I've tried using the install.sh file (making it executable and then executing it) and also making/installing just the driver folder itself - no joy with either method.

The install.sh file is now completing without causing the corruption problems I had originally:
Below is the conclusion at the end of the install.sh execution script and lsmod shows the 8812au driver (first line after lsmod)

```
##################################################
Compile make driver ok!!
##################################################
./install.sh: 68: [: unexpected operator
Authentication requested [root] for remove driver:
Password: 
Error: Module 8812au is not currently loaded
Authentication requested [root] for insert driver:
Password: 
Authentication requested [root] for install driver:
Password: 
install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 3.11.0-12-generic
##################################################
The Setup Script is completed !
##################################################
ken@ken-1005HA ~/Downloads/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8812au                905927  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12617  0 
usb_storage            48294  0 
eeepc_wmi              12983  0 
asus_wmi               23495  1 eeepc_wmi
coretemp               13195  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 asus_wmi
joydev                 17097  0 
bnep                   18893  2 
dm_multipath           22402  0 
rfcomm                 53664  0 
parport_pc             31981  0 
scsi_dh                14458  1 dm_multipath
arc4                   12536  2 
ppdev                  17391  0 
bluetooth             323534  10 bnep,rfcomm
ath9k                 135969  0 
ath9k_common           13619  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              429197  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    19187  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
```

however when I plug in the adapter it is not activated:

After re-starting I don't initially see 8812au listed when I request lsmod;
but if I plug in the the adapter, then I do.
However if I physically remove it, the driver remains loaded. 
In this state, the Terminal will not respond to most commands (other than list) and neither software manager or upgrade drivers will load from the Menu. If I restart the system, these will all function normally before the USB adapter is inserted.

If I request modinfo 8812au I get this:

```
$ modinfo 8812au
filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8812au.ko
version:        v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     3D847C44AE897B16DFCA0EB
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.11.0-12-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_regulatory_id:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
```

**More:**

I disabled my internal wireless adapter - ath9k - in case of conflicts with both running - it definitely is stopped, but still nothing on the usb adapter

Next - rfkill list

```
1. asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: no
```

**Edit:** 
Found that the issue is, 4.2.5 will not load into 3.11 kernel;

However WILL successfully install in <3.10 - I ran it in 3.8 and it installed with no issues.

Also pleased to report that the performance issues associated with 4.2.2 appear to have been improved considerably in 4.2.5

So - **PARTIALLY RESOLVED** - in that the 4.2.5 driver will work in kernel <3.10
Hopefully a full fix will come with a modification to run in 3.11

Now - **COMPLETELY RESOLVED** - great job by abperiasamy to see what the conflict was in 3.11 and modify so now we have a loadable working driver with the improved range!  https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/1

Comment: Could really use some guidance here. chili555 where are you? :) The 4.2.5 driver from the Asus looks like it may specifically address the issue described immediately above "Update MAC/BB/RF parameters and mechanism to improve overall performance." I just cannot get this loaded whether I try the install.sh file or try to make and install just the driver itself

Comment: I was able to validate that 4.2.5 works on a 3.8 kernel - the issue is that it will not run on 3.11 (hence the issues I was having getting it to run).  4.2.5 definitely addresses the performance issues of 4.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Now - COMPLETELY RESOLVED - great job by abperiasamy to see what the conflict was in 3.11 and modify so now we have a loadable working driver with the improved range! https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Hi everyone, I purchased the USB Asus AC56R for Ubuntu 14.04, and installed the driver from the ASUS website,  then SUDO broke!!!  rendered my system useless.  Please BE VERY CAREFUL and backup your system before trusting Asus drivers.