# Drivers for new network card

Tags: networking, hardware

Yesterday i bought a new network card ASUS PCE-AC56 (Not an USB-adapter) for my desktop which only runs on ubuntu. I quickly found out that i need som drivers for it to work, but i cant seem to find any solution for that. I'm currently writing on my macbook air. My desktop is offline, can someone help me get it back online?
I think it's worth mention that i'm a noob with linux..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install an ASUS USB-AC56 WiFi adapter?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/404881/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-ac56-wifi-adapter)

Comment: It's not an usb adapter. Not exactly the same i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your network card does not comes with a CD driver? maybe it has some files or scripts.
Can you check please what is the output of: `lspci`

and you can filter the result with this: `$ lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %`

Comment: manually written:
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 13)
Subsystem: Micro-star international Co., ltd. [MSI] Device 7816 Kernel driver in use: alx

Comment: lspci -nn | grep 0280 gives:

Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless network adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)

Comment: Ok I see that doesnt recognizes the connection, I was searching and I [found](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCEAC56/) that specially this adapter does not have official support on linux, that answer my question about  the CD driver

Comment: Yeah, but is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Well you can try installing the right and latest broadcom drivers, like this [site](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_PCE-AC56) show. There is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~albertomilone/+archive/ubuntu/broadcom) too, maybe you can make it works, or try with the broadcom [binary file](http://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1)

Comment: Ok, i will try the binary file. How do i run it?

Comment: It is not really a executable file like you imagine, you need to compile it, and run it, instructions are [here](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.271.txt) or the easy way is search how compile  in youtube, or get the .deb file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta)

Comment: HeyHeyHey! Binary works like a charm, thanks! :) SOLVED!

Comment: Ah, after i restarted my computer, i can't detect my card again. do you have a soloution for that? Do i have to do the same thing over after each restart?

Comment: The only thing that you have to do is try to get the card working again and try with: modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
and watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlLS8d4Z09c) video for autostart the module of the wifi card when you reboot